# What do you call a "circle-ish" polygon with 256 sides?

Tags: geometry, terminology, polygons

I would like to find an image of such a geometric shape or generate one myself, but I am not sure what to look for.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you would call it other than a $256$-gon. A regular one would probably be the most circle-ish.

Comment: A 256-gon? https://www.desmos.com/calculator/abgjty3zr4

Comment: You can do that easily with [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org).

Comment: Some regular polygons with lots of sides do have names: $1,000$ sides = Chiliagon, $10,000$ sides = Myriagon, and $1,000,000$ sides = Megagon. Those are the ones I know of, anyway, and they are all "circle-ish".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [dihectapentacontahexagon](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/ue8dee8d4-5903-469e-88f1-d8b069ea2d12/Dihectapentacontahexagon?hl=en).

For a more general answer, see [List of polygons - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_polygons#Systematic_polygon_names).

The late John H. Conway mentions a few other such names [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57666.html).